# Select something from a database where id is equal to a variable

Tags: mysql

I want to select a row from a database table, using where `id= 'x'`. 
The thing is that I want to be able to change that 'x' dynamically, so if I need to select a row where `id= 'y'`, I want to be able to just load y in another row and read it from that row.

Sorry for my bad english.

```
<?php
 $id = a field from another table

 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM text where id= '$id'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['text_area'];
        } 
?>
```

Here is an image that I hope will explain this better.
[image: http://concordia.com.ro/hmm.jpg]

Comment: I see no bad English here

Comment: Really sorry could not understand this part ` The thing is that I want to be able to change that 'x' dynamically, so if I need to select a row where id= 'y', I want to be able to just load y in another row and read it from that row.` . Can you explain more ? and your English is good but just explain it in another way if that's ok .

Comment: Basically I will have 2 tables. In one of them I will save a number, for example 1258 and in the other one i will have a bunch of data. I want to be able to only show (from the table with that bunch of data) that row that have a specific id and that id I want to be that 1258.

Comment: So instead SELECT * FROM despre where id= '1258' i want to be where id= whatever is written in the first table

Comment: do you have id field in the other table ?

Comment: Or whatever is written in that table, in a field, either is good

Comment: I hope this will clarify http://concordia.com.ro/tabela.jpg

Comment: @AlexandruChirigiu show me the second table

Comment: So val_id should be here SELECT * FROM despre where id= 'val_id'. If is easier, I can put val_id in the main field. http://concordia.com.ro/tabela2.jpg

Comment: ok i think i got your Q , i will post an answer with an eample that i created , understand it if thats what you were asking for tell me to edit small things in your code @AlexandruChirigiu

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: check the answer and see the example , read it and make sure to understand it , if that was not what you are looking for then we have to start from the start

Comment: @AlexandruChirigiu have you saw the answer ?

Comment: Really sorry , im lost with the Q , sorry i did my best lol

Comment: If i wasn't clear enough please tell me and i will try to explain it better.

Comment: yea if you can please do it .

Comment: Look here bro http://concordia.com.ro/hmm.jpg

Comment: @AlexandruChirigiu try this : <?php  

 $GetValue = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT value FROM id_val");
 $GV = mysqli_fetch_array($GetValue);
 
 $Value = $GV['value'];
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM despre where id= $Value ");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo $row['despre_caption'];
 }   
        
?>    This is an image for the code http://prntscr.com/cdupw7

Comment: Thanks bro!!!! It works!!!

Comment: <?php

$GetValue = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT value FROM id_val"); 
$GV = mysqli_fetch_array($GetValue); 

$Value = $GV['value']; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM text where id= $Value "); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ echo $row['text_area']; } 
?>   just those tabels name were different. Ty again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
 $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM id_val");

 while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM text where id= '{$row1['value']}'");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
         echo $row['text_area'];
     }
 }
?>
```

Comment: If you can take a look here http://concordia.com.ro/hmm.jpg . That is what i need, which is pretty close to ^.